# preg_replace with arrays - trim replacement

Tags: php, html, twitter, preg-replace

I've been using Twitter REST API and have found the tweet data does not automatically wrap links in anchor tags. So I've written a PHP function to search each tweet text and do this for me.

It finds anything beginning with '@' or '#' as well as regular links and replaces them with the relevant markup. The problem I have is where I've put the expression found back into the replacement, I need to remove the leading '@' or '#' from the actual link href.

How do I do that?

```
function tTweet($tTweet){
    $tPattern = array(
                  '/(http:\/\/t\.co\/[a-z0-9]+)/i', 
                  '/(@[a-z0-9]+)/i', 
                  '/(#[a-z0-9]+)/i' );

    $tReplace = array(
                  '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', 
                  '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',
                  '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1&src=hash" target="_blank">$1</a>' );

    echo preg_replace($tPattern,$tReplace,$tTweet); 
}
```

Comment: Move it out of / before the `(..)` capture group.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @mario, yes I see it was a duplicate now. Didn't find that thread before.